# get posts where a custom field contains a text

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I have a custom field where the value contains a comma separated list of items (like: `test1,test2,test3`), now I want to retrieve posts where the field contains one of the values, I have:

```
$query = get_posts( 
    array( 
        'post_type'      => 'custom_post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 11, 
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_my_custom_field_key',
                'value'   => array('test1'),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        ) 
    ) 
);
```

And it fails. It works if I clear other values from the custom field so it only contains `test1` but not when it's in the comma-separated group.
In SQL I can use `FIND_IN_SET` function to search for the value, but I'm trying to reply on core WP as much as possible and avoid custom SQL codes, it would be cool if it were possible.

Comment: BTW here's a working SQL query:
`
$query = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = '_my_custom_field_key' AND FIND_IN_SET( 'test1', meta_value ) > 0" );
`

Comment: Please add this extra information into the question, which should contain all the relevant information and it's easier to read, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here are few ideas:

1) You could try to compare with `LIKE` instead:

```
'key'     => '_my_custom_field_key',              
'value'   => 'test1',                
'compare' => 'LIKE'
```

It should give you a SQL query with:

```
... LIKE '%test1%' ...
```

2) You might want to save the string as

```
,test1,test2,test3,
```

to make the whole word search easier:

```
'key'     => '_my_custom_field_key',              
'value'   => ',test1,',                
'compare' => 'LIKE'
```

3) Another option would be to save it to a meta key with multiple values.

4) You could also modify the generated SQL query via filters like [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) and [`posts_clauses`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses). Notice that `get_posts()` suppresses filters by default, but you can use the `suppress_filters` parameter to control it, or use `WP_Query()` instead.

5) Manually write the SQL query and fetch it with the `$wpdb` class, like you are doing already.

Comment: I'm not sure `like` is the best solution, if you query for `test` for example it will return all three values of `test1, test2, test3` I think.

Comment: @a378853 I added few more options that you might consider.